# Ankhsvn Error: Client too old to work with working copy

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2005, ankhsvn

I am using Ankhsvn 2.0.6347.433 with Visual Studio 2005 and it's reporting that Ankhsvn's subversion client is too old for the working copy. The given error links to http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#working-copy-format-change which talks about using a 1.4.4 subversion client on a subversion 1.5 formated checkout.

Ankhsvn's [home page](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/servlets/ProjectProcess?pageID=3794) says that Ankhsvn 2.0 and above uses subversion 1.5 internally. The link doesn't mention anything about 1.5 clients having issues.

My own limited troubleshooting hasn't turned up anything I can directly point to but I do have TortoiseSVN 1.6.1 installed which uses Subversion 1.6.1 internally. I have a habit of using TortoiseSVN to commit stuff in my project folder which would bypass anything Ankhsvn is doing. Would this be causing a similar problem that trying to use 1.4.4 and 1.5 clients would cause or is something else happening?

**Edit: Okay, I shouldn't mix 1.6 and 1.5 clients.**

How do I fix this? I would like to use AnkhSVN if possible.

Comment: It's better to ask questions like this at the project's mailing list / forum, instead of asking it here. It's also not a programming question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look on the [release notes](http://subversion.tigris.org/svn_1.6_releasenotes.html) for subversion 1.6 you will see the following

> The working copy format has been upgraded. This means that 1.5 and older Subversion clients will not be able to work with working copies produced by Subversion 1.6. Working copies are upgraded automatically.

So if you use a 1.6 based client, no previous versions will work. On further reading of the release notes you should be able to downgrade your working copy if required...

> WARNING: if a Subversion 1.6 client encounters a pre-1.6 working copy, it will automatically upgrade the working copy format as soon as it touches it, making it unreadable by older Subversion clients. If you are using several versions of Subversion on your machine, be careful about which version you use in which working copy, to avoid accidentally upgrading a working copy. (But note that this "auto upgrade" behavior does not occur with the repositories, only working copies.)
>
> If you accidentally upgrade a 1.5 working copy to 1.6, and wish to downgrade back to 1.5, use the change-svn-wc-format.py script. See this FAQ entry for details, and run the script with the --help option for usage instructions.

Comment: AnkhSVN 2.1 uses Subversion 1.6.. See the daily builds on http://ankhsvn.net/daily (And future stable releases)

Answer (score 5):

Brett gets my +1, and for svn 1.6 support in Ankh, use a [daily](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/daily/) build.

Comment: They are release quality, but lack tree conflict resolution (tree conflicts are new types of conflicts in 1.6) See the 1.6 release notes for more on this.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to using a daily build for Ankh (see Si's answer!) is revert to TortoiseSVN 1.5.9 which used SVN 1.5. That will force you to downgrade your working copy to 1.5 (see Brett's answer!).

There is a link to download the 1.5.9 version [here](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=138498&package_id=151948).

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem just occur to me. Perhaps it does not apply for your situation, but maybe it will help someone else.

I have dual-boot windows & ubuntu. In the terminal in ubuntu I was getting that error when trying to update, but after reading comments regarding the format change, I verified that I already had the newest version.

Then it dawned on me that the folder I was trying to update in was created by Tortoise / Ankh in windows; I just made a separate folder for the linux versions of code, which makes sense anyway since the build files are different.